# Error 400 Your request is invalid in yii if i am creating link

Tags: yii

I'm pretty new to Yii, so this might be a silly question. I must be missing something somewhere. Plz help me out.
I have just written a simple code while I'm learning Yii.
I have a spark controller which has an action that looks like this:

```
public function actionDownload($name){

          $filecontent=file_get_contents('images/spark/'.$name);
          header("Content-Type: text/plain");
          header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=$name");
          header("Pragma: no-cache");
          echo $filecontent;
          exit;
    }
```

Now I have enabled SEO friendly URLs and echo statement in the view file to display the returned download file name.
But when I go to the URL, 
**SITE_NAME/index.php/spark/download/db5250efc9a9684ceaa25cacedef81cd.pdf**
I get error 400 - your request is invalid.

Plz let me know if I am missing something here.

Answer (score 4):

Yii keeps an eye on the params you pass into an `action` function. Any params you pass must match what's in `$_GET`.

So if you're passing `$name` then you need to make sure there's `$_GET['name']` available.

So check your URL manager in `/config/main.php`, and make sure you're declaring a GET var:

```
'spark/download/<name:[a-z0-9]+>' => 'site/download', // Setting up $_GET['name']
```

Otherwise change your function to the correct param variable:

```
public function actionDownload($anotherName){

}
```

Comment: Hi @User1988 - did my answer help you? I'd love an accepted tick if my answer was correct and useful :)

Comment: Appreciate this, was doing my head in. Just had to rename the post url. Cheers man

Answer (score 1):

Did you create the URL correct? You should do it best with

```
Yii::app()->createUrl('/spark/download',array('name'=>$filename));
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure if you are properly supplying the parameter `name` (`$name`) in your request.

Use

*SITE_NAME/index.php/spark/download/**name**/db5250efc9a9684ceaa25cacedef81cd.pdf*

or

*SITE_NAME/index.php/spark/download?**name**=db5250efc9a9684ceaa25cacedef81cd.pdf*

instead of just *SITE_NAME/index.php/spark/download/db5250efc9a9684ceaa25cacedef81cd.pdf*